# Derived table in AOT data dictionary table not reflecting in SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Reading upon this documentation about AOT tables:

"Tables store business data. Each table in the AOT has a corresponding table in the underlying Microsoft SQL Server database."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/tables-views-and-maps

However, upon doing some select queries in SQL Server, there is one derived table in AOT, that is NOT reflecting in the SQL Server database.

As I do select query for this table, it results to

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
>   Invalid object name 'BaseTableName'

Hope to get some light about this issue, if this is some db synchronization issue or base table (which extends to other derived table) from AOT does not really reflect in the SQL Server database counterpart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All fields defined in Dynamics AX in derived tables are placed directly in base table in database.
The derived tables exist as independent objects in application layer only.
Since all the derived tables data are stored in base table, AX differentiate them by a column `InstanceRelationType` which is RelationType EDT. Values in `InstanceRelationType` represents table IDs.

Comment: Note that in pre AX 2012 R2 versions, the base and derived tables also lived in the database. In R2 they changed the implementation to only have the base table with all fields in the database. See also [Queries to tables with inheritance](http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2012/11/queries-to-tables-with-inheritance/) and [Selecting Data from a Table Inheritance Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/selecting-data-from-a-table-inheritance-hierarchy)